# Authorization headers not correctly being added in Axios instance using inceptors

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, authorization

I am trying to make a Get API call with authorization (using a JWT token). I have created a separate Axios instance and trying to attach the authorization token using the Axios interceptors. I am getting status 200 while trying with Postman and the same token, but when making the API call from am getting Status 403 (Forbidden).

My Axios implementation is:

```
let Authinstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: SERVER_URL + '/api',
    headers:{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
})

Authinstance.interceptors.request.use( config => {
    const token = Auth().getToken();
    config.headers['Authorization'] =  `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
})

export const getPayees = async() => {
    const username = Auth().getUser();
    const res = await Authinstance.get(`/netbanking/beneficiary/${username}`)

    return res.data
}
```

The function `Auth().getToken()` just fetches and returns the token from sessionStorage.
As you can see in the given image, I am getting a 403 status from the server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDqvt.png)

My intuition is that I am doing something wrong in implementation of Axios, as I am not familiar with the flow of code for Axios. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Screen shows the option request, can you try to put screen for second request. But can you try to do this:

```
const authHeader = () => {
  Axios.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
         const token = Auth().getToken();
        config.headers['Authorization'] =  `Bearer ${token}`;
        config.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
        config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        return config;
      },
      err => {
          return Promise.reject(err);
      }
  );
}
```

and your implementation will be:

```
// ----- authHeader ------

let Authinstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: SERVER_URL + '/api',
    headers: authHeader(),
})

export const getPayees = async() => {
    const username = Auth().getUser();
    const res = await Authinstance.get(`/netbanking/beneficiary/${username}`)
    return res.data
}
```

Let me know if it can works.